# react, incompatible override, should have signature

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I use the shouldComponentUpdate function , 
webStorm gives a warning `incompatible override, should have signature ....`, 
but the code working well. Do I miss some bug, that I didn't realise?

The code:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.TAC.length === 8 && nextProps.TAC !== this.props.TAC){
      fetch(`http://${host}:3001/searchHistory`,{
        method:'post',
        headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
        credentials:'include',
        body:JSON.stringify({TAC:Number(nextProps.TAC)})
      }).then(res=>res.json())
        .then(result=>{
          if(result){
            Alert.alert('提示','该信息为今天录入／已经缓存',[
              {text:'取消', onPress:()=>this.props.toggleStatus(false)},
              {text:'查看',onPress:()=>this.props.toggleStatus(true)},
            ],{
              cancelable:false
            })
          }
        });
    }
    return nextProps !== this.props
  }
```

[image: Code]

Comment: Can you provide the code of your tries? not only image https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [Looks like this is a known issue](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206589469-WebStorm-ReactJS-Incompatible-override-and-returned-expression-XML-is-not-assignable-to-ReactElement) - [tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29074)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the missing parameter `nextState` and WebStorm will be happy

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)
```

"[Signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature)" means the number and type of function's parameters defined in class React.Component or React.PureComponent extended by your component.

Comment: Thanks. finally, I add three parameter  then WebStorm doesn't warn anymore. ```shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps,nextState,nextContent)```

Comment: If I add the `nextContext` param to the `shouldComponentUpdate` function I get an error from ESLint `ESLint: 'nextContext' is defined but never used. (no-unused-vars`, normally, because I do not use the `nextContext` anywhere. Is there another way to fix the WebStorm warning?

Comment: Same for my linter rules as @Sabbin